# Android application crashes when showing multiple images in GridView component

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-gridview

I am fairly new to this site and I'm here because I couldn't find this answer anywhere else so I would like to see if I could get some help!

I have a GridView in my project as well as a Image Adapter. I need help with the following code:

```
package com.humanoid.sigma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


public Integer[] Tattoos = {
        R.drawable.tattoo1, R.drawable.tattoo2,
        R.drawable.tattoo3, R.drawable.tattoo4,
        R.drawable.tattoo5, /*R.drawable.tattoo6,
        R.drawable.tattoo7, R.drawable.tattoo8,
        R.drawable.tattoo9, R.drawable.tattoo10, 
        R.drawable.tattoo11, R.drawable.tattoo12,
        R.drawable.tattoo13, R.drawable.tattoo14,
        R.drawable.tattoo15, R.drawable.tattoo16,
        R.drawable.tattoo17, R.drawable.tattoo18,
        R.drawable.tattoo19, R.drawable.tattoo20, 
        R.drawable.tattoo21, R.drawable.tattoo22,
        R.drawable.tattoo23, R.drawable.tattoo24,
        R.drawable.tattoo25, R.drawable.tattoo26,
        R.drawable.tattoo27, R.drawable.tattoo28,
        R.drawable.tattoo29, R.drawable.tattoo30, 
        R.drawable.tattoo31, R.drawable.tattoo32,
        R.drawable.tattoo33, R.drawable.tattoo34,
        R.drawable.tattoo35, R.drawable.tattoo36,
        R.drawable.tattoo37, R.drawable.tattoo38,
        R.drawable.tattoo39, R.drawable.tattoo40, 
        R.drawable.tattoo41, R.drawable.tattoo42,
        R.drawable.tattoo43, R.drawable.tattoo44,
        R.drawable.tattoo45, R.drawable.tattoo46,
        R.drawable.tattoo47, R.drawable.tattoo48,
        R.drawable.tattoo49, R.drawable.tattoo50, 
        R.drawable.tattoo51, R.drawable.tattoo52,
        R.drawable.tattoo53, R.drawable.tattoo54,
        R.drawable.tattoo55, R.drawable.tattoo56,
        R.drawable.tattoo57, R.drawable.tattoo58,
        R.drawable.tattoo59, R.drawable.tattoo60, 
        R.drawable.tattoo61, R.drawable.tattoo62,
        R.drawable.tattoo63, R.drawable.tattoo64,
        R.drawable.tattoo65, R.drawable.tattoo66,
        R.drawable.tattoo67, R.drawable.tattoo68,
        R.drawable.tattoo69, R.drawable.tattoo70, 
        R.drawable.tattoo71, R.drawable.tattoo72,
        R.drawable.tattoo73, R.drawable.tattoo74,
        R.drawable.tattoo75, R.drawable.tattoo76,
        R.drawable.tattoo77, R.drawable.tattoo78,
        R.drawable.tattoo79, R.drawable.tattoo80,
        R.drawable.tattoo81, R.drawable.tattoo82,*/

};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return Tattoos.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Tattoos[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(Tattoos[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 70));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Logcat Stack Trace:

> 06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):
>     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:349) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   com.humanoid.sigma.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:80) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:985) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-28 17:51:14.104:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   06-28 17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 06-28
>   17:51:14.104: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Gallery.Java code:

```
package com.humanoid.sigma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Gallery extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photos);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullScreen.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

As you can see from above, I have commented out what isn't working for me. I don't know if it's because I have too many pictures for this GridView but it's rather annoying. Once I commented those images out the program runs fine but if I delete the /* and run the program and select Gallery, it would just show a black screen. Shortly after it would crash.

Please help me with this code I keep searching but can't find anything to help.

Comment: give us logcat stack trace

Comment: Okay I've edited the post above in order to see the Logcat Stack Trace.

Comment: Sorry about how it looks. I couldn't get it to look neat unfortunately.

Comment: I cant really find anything useful in your stack trace

Comment: look here at the `getView` method: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3614779/1276374

Comment: So there isn't anything that could help with this except rewrite the whole code? I saw the link you gave me but would that support 82+ images? Just curious.

Comment: let me try out your code

Comment: ok, now i see what happens, it is actually `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget` (simply not enough memory on the heap) is what happens. Are you trying to run this code on emulator or on actual device? I believe, that device will allow more space allocation that VM, but i am not sure about that. There are many ways of showing drawables more efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem arises due to the exhaustion of the heap size while allocating drawable resources (it is a common problem, since lots of memory required for this kind of operation).

When i have tried your code, i got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget` . Which is a straightforward self-explanatory error message.

Then i made some research and came across a 'native' thread on official Android Dev website: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html about Bitmaps and examples on how to make efficient resource allocations in applications.

So I tried it and combined with your code and this is what i got:

**ImageAdapter.java** :

```
package com.humanoid.sigma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


public Integer[] Tattoos = {
        R.drawable.tattoo1, R.drawable.tattoo2,
        R.drawable.tattoo3, R.drawable.tattoo4,
        R.drawable.tattoo5, R.drawable.tattoo6,
        R.drawable.tattoo7, R.drawable.tattoo8,
        R.drawable.tattoo9, R.drawable.tattoo10, 
        R.drawable.tattoo11, R.drawable.tattoo12,
        R.drawable.tattoo13, R.drawable.tattoo14,
        R.drawable.tattoo15, R.drawable.tattoo16,
        R.drawable.tattoo17, R.drawable.tattoo18,
        R.drawable.tattoo19, R.drawable.tattoo20, 
        R.drawable.tattoo21, R.drawable.tattoo22,
        R.drawable.tattoo23, R.drawable.tattoo24,
        R.drawable.tattoo25, R.drawable.tattoo26,
        R.drawable.tattoo27, R.drawable.tattoo28,
        R.drawable.tattoo29, R.drawable.tattoo30, 
        R.drawable.tattoo31, R.drawable.tattoo32,
        R.drawable.tattoo33, R.drawable.tattoo34,
        R.drawable.tattoo35, R.drawable.tattoo36,
        R.drawable.tattoo37, R.drawable.tattoo38,
        R.drawable.tattoo39, R.drawable.tattoo40, 
        R.drawable.tattoo41, R.drawable.tattoo42,
        R.drawable.tattoo43, R.drawable.tattoo44,
        R.drawable.tattoo45, R.drawable.tattoo46,
        R.drawable.tattoo47, R.drawable.tattoo48,
        R.drawable.tattoo49, R.drawable.tattoo50, 
        R.drawable.tattoo51, R.drawable.tattoo52,
        R.drawable.tattoo53, R.drawable.tattoo54,
        R.drawable.tattoo55, R.drawable.tattoo56,
        R.drawable.tattoo57, R.drawable.tattoo58,
        R.drawable.tattoo59, R.drawable.tattoo60, 
        R.drawable.tattoo61, R.drawable.tattoo62,
        R.drawable.tattoo63, R.drawable.tattoo64,
        R.drawable.tattoo65, R.drawable.tattoo66,
        R.drawable.tattoo67, R.drawable.tattoo68,
        R.drawable.tattoo69, R.drawable.tattoo70, 
        R.drawable.tattoo71, R.drawable.tattoo72,
        R.drawable.tattoo73, R.drawable.tattoo74,
        R.drawable.tattoo75, R.drawable.tattoo76,
        R.drawable.tattoo77, R.drawable.tattoo78,
        R.drawable.tattoo79, R.drawable.tattoo80,
        R.drawable.tattoo81, R.drawable.tattoo82

};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return Tattoos.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Tattoos[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //This actually is a bad solution, because every time convertView is reused, you will still initialize new ImageView, which is wrong
    //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
    //new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
    //return imageView;

    //Better solution
    ImageView imageView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(this.mContext);
        new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(Tattoos[position]);
        //create new ImageView if it is not present and populate it with some image
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        //re-use ImageView that already exists in memory
    }

return imageView;
}


class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private int data = 0;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ImageAdapter.this.mContext.getResources(), data, 100, 100);
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 70));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

Which loads images asynchronously and does some additional magic on loaded resources.

This solution works fine for me and when you run your code, you can actually see images being loaded one at a time, starting with one that is of less weight and going upwards, i guess, because for every `ImageView` there will be a separate worker `Thread`, which will load and transform the resource and then apply it to the `ImageView`.

Proof:

[image: asynctask load of resources in getview method inside custom adapter]

Comment: I like how you set up the code but how do I implement this into my code? Sorry but I'm rather new to the whole development of Android.

Comment: @Kodi I edited my answer, just copy all the code you see above to your class implementation. Hope this helps

Comment: Just tried it out and it didn't work. I put a screenshot of what I should change the context to. It gave me three options but I tried "Create field 'context' in type 'ImageAdapter" and "Change to mContext". The first just crashed the gallery and wouldn't let me open the other xml layout while the later let me open the gallery but once I continued to the xml layout it took a few seconds of black screen and then it crashed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: So apparently I can't add a photo or upvote your post -_- but the other option was "Create constant 'context' in type 'ImageAdapter"

Comment: @Kodi yeah, you are doing something wrong. And i did something wrong too in my answer, since i made my own code just reusing some parts of yours, i used my own variable names.. whatever. So in order for it to work - change `context` variable name to `mContext`. Since it is the context of the main activity that you would want to preserve. I edited my answer

Comment: Tried it once again and it crashed. I'll post my other .Java code that connects to the ImageAdapter.

Comment: Commented out some of the Images and kept 7. Worked just fine! You think it's just the mass amount of data?

Comment: @Kodi I just tried with 30 without any problem. Are you trying on Emulator or on device?

Comment: I just did 30 images as well and it ran just fine. I am running it on an Emulator and haven't tried it on a device yet. There aren't any errors that are coming up in the logs but what I've found interesting is that it just shows me a little bit of the photo while viewing it in GridView and it doesn't show all the other photos except for three.

Comment: @Kodi well, maybe there is a problem with photos

Comment: They're all PNG files but do you think it's just the size of those files that are making them not load correctly?

Comment: @Kodi just had some variations in my drawables, some of size 500Kb, some 1Mb, some, like http://oenvoyage.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/huge4.jpg, 4.5Mb and one .png of size 1.5Mb. Got no exceptions, no nothing, everything run smoothly. Which folder do you store your drawables?

Comment: @Kodi `There aren't any errors that are coming up in the logs` that is not possible

Comment: @Kodi I tried now with different folders too, no problem, everything works just fine

Comment: @Kodi I advise you to try to run on the actual device even though I am running this code on 2.1 emulator

Comment: All of my images are smaller the Mb (all in the Kb range). I don't know what could be the problem? When I ran it on the emulator it said in the log that the .apk package failed to install yet it was on there and I was able to open it. I will try it on a Device and check back here as soon as possible! Also, I don't know what emulator I'm running on. Out of date maybe?

Comment: So I tried it out and it's the same result on the Device as well. Sigh. If I could upload a screenshot I would but I can't T_T

Comment: @Kodi send it over to my email: iphoneetc@gmail.com  and please, find stack trace, when you are getting an error. Better send the whole project, so I can test it

Comment: I sent it! Hopefully you can find out whatever it is that I did wrong with my project

Comment: @Kodi After analyzing your code, i can say that in your `gallery.xml` file you must change `android:layout_height` of your `GridView` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`. Because pictures are actually being loaded, but since height was assigned to `wrap_content`, there was insufficient height for the gallery show images

Comment: @Kodi I see that you will have another problem with scrolling later. But then you have to solve it on your own or ask another question on StackOverflow regarding this issue

Comment: @Kodi ok, i can give you a better solution, which will solve the problem with scrolling (because it is my original mistake). I have updated the code in my answer, so look at `getView` method

Comment: Awesome! I'm trying it out now!

Comment: You sir are amazing!!! It works!!!!!! Thank you so much for helping me with this project! I was honestly lost but thanks to you it works like a charm. Thank you again!

Comment: Since I can't upvote your answer I'll just give you a comment upvote ^^^^^