# how convertView change in getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) in this example

Tags: android, android-adapter

can you please explain for me how `convertView` will changed in this example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// If we weren't given a view, inflate one
  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
  }
  // Configure the view for this Crime
  Crime c = getItem(position);
  TextView titleTextView =
    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
  titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
  TextView dateTextView =
    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
  dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());
  CheckBox solvedCheckBox =
    (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
  solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isSolved());
  return convertView;
}
```

i want to know how `titleTextView` & `dataTextView` & `solvedCheckBox` affect on convertView???
or the `convertView` that returned at the end of method is the same as `convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);` and  `titleTextView` & `dataTextView` & `solvedCheckBox` do not changed any thing in `convertView`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (convertView == null) {
convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
```

}

This is the initialization of the convertView you need to do it only first time then it will not needed for the second time And titleTextView & dataTextView & solvedCheckBox don't affect on convertView

Comment: so  `titleTextView` & `dataTextView` & `solvedCheckBox` never changed the convertView neither in first time and after  that???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614779/how-is-the-getview-method-used-and-where-is-it-getting-called

Comment: Are you facing any problem with this code or just want to know what is happening here?

Comment: @AnirudhNegi just want to know what is happening, the code is correct

Comment: got answer by NilayDani  or still confused?

Comment: @AnirudhNegi TnX, i got

Comment: @AnirudhNegi if we have a arraylist with length of 100 and want to show them in a ViewList how many times getView() will execute???100times???

Comment: @hamid_c it will execute 100 times but not all at once.. first time it will be called for no. of items visible to you.. then when you scroll, it will be called for each visible list item that you see subsequently..